# Removed wrong registry.How to recover it. 4D36E966-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry

I tried to remove

```
upperfilters of 4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318
```

but I have removed

```
upperfilters of 4D36E966-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318
```

now I cannot start my computer and I have tried system restore, startup repair.

If you know the value of

```
hkey_local_machine/system/currentcontrolset/control/class/{4D36E966-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
```

upperfilters please tell me.

Comment: Restore from your backups. You do have backups, right? If not, then this is a valuable lesson for you the learn today.

Comment: Please see the value of hkey_local_machine/system/currentcontrolset/control/class/{4D36E966-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318} from your computer and tell me

Answer (score 4):

#### Removed wrong registry entry 4D36E966-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318

For what it's worth, the entry on my machine (Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit) is:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E966-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}]
"Class"="Computer"
"ClassDesc"="@%SystemRoot%\\System32\\SysClass.dll,-3000"
@="Computer"
"IconPath"=hex(7):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,65,00,74,00,75,00,70,00,61,00,70,00,69,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,\
  2d,00,32,00,37,00,00,00,00,00
"Installer32"="SysClass.dll,ComputerClassInstaller"
"NoInstallClass"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E966-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0000]
"ResourcePickerTags"="HAL"
"InfPath"="hal.inf"
"InfSection"="ACPI_AMD64_HAL"
"ProviderName"="Microsoft"
"DriverDateData"=hex:00,80,8c,a3,c5,94,c6,01
"DriverDate"="6-21-2006"
"DriverVersion"="6.1.7600.16385"
"MatchingDeviceId"="acpiapic"
"DriverDesc"="ACPI x64-based PC"
```

---

#### I have removed `UpperFilters` of `4D36E966-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318`

You can't remove what isn't there.

That registry entry doesn't have an `UpperFilters` key as it is not of class `DVD/CD-ROM Drives`.

The value for the registry entry `4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318` is `GEARAspiWDM`

See [How to Delete the UpperFilters and LowerFilters Values](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-delete-the-upperfilters-and-lowerfilters-registry-values-2619222) for more information.

---

#### How Do I Restore a Registry Backup if I Can’t Boot?

> It really depends on the kind of failure that you’re experiencing.
>
> I want to be clear about one thing when it comes to registry backups:
>   they are not a complete backup solution. Even if what’s preventing you
>   from booting is a registry issue, the only real, true backup solution
>   to the scenario that you described is a full image or machine backup.
>   A registry backup simply cannot save you from every possible failure
>   mode – even those that involve the registry itself.
>
> **How to restore your registry**
>
> I don’t know how your machine is failing to reboot – meaning I don’t
>   know exactly what symptoms you’re seeing – but see if you can boot
>   your machine in Safe Mode. During the early boot process, right after
>   the BIOS self test, press F8 to get the boot choice menu and select
>   the option to boot into Safe Mode.
>
> Safe Mode can often sidestep some of the issues that prevent a full
>   boot from working and it’s perfect for restoring the registry. In
>   fact, that’s what most computer repair professional will choose when
>   doing a full registry restore.
>
> [image]

Source [How Do I Restore a Registry Backup if I Can't Boot? - Ask Leo!](https://askleo.com/how-do-i-restore-a-registry-backup-if-i-cant-boot/)

---

#### What if I can boot into Safe Mode?

If you can boot into Safe Mode, try the following:

> ```
> C:\windows\system32\config\regback>copy default.old c:\windows\system32\default
> C:\windows\system32\config\regback>copy sam.old c:\windows\system32\sam
> C:\windows\system32\config\regback>copy security.old c:\windows\system32\security
> C:\windows\system32\config\regback>copy software.old c:\windows\system32\software
> C:\windows\system32\config\regback>copy system.old c:\windows\system32\system
> ```

Source [How to recover from a corrupted registry that prevents Windows 7 from - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-recover-from-a-corrupted-registry-that/3319876e-76e3-4eb4-a59f-53b5eb476c24)

---

#### I can't boot into Safe Mode.

> For a full, catastrophic failure where the registry itself – or for
>   that matter just about anything – prevents you from rebooting into
>   Windows, a backup of the registry is simply not enough.
>
> You may need a full system backup that you can then restore to get
>   your machine working once again.

Source [How Do I Restore a Registry Backup if I Can't Boot? - Ask Leo!](https://askleo.com/how-do-i-restore-a-registry-backup-if-i-cant-boot/)

---

#### I was able to start with Last Known Good Configuration. What do I do now?

You are good to go.

> Last Known Good Configuration loads the drivers and registry data that worked the last time you successfully started and then shut down Windows 7.

Source [How to Start Windows 7 Using Last Known Good Configuration](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-start-windows-7-using-last-known-good-configuration-2626308)

Now would be a good time to backup your system ...

Comment: If you have a computer please look and tell me the value

Comment: @SakithKarunasena Did you read my answer? It's right at the top ...

Comment: Is the value 'Computer'

Comment: {sigh} Read my answer carefully.

Comment: Just to complement the above Reg info, on Windows 10 Pro except for a different icon number and DriverVersion is exactly the same

Comment: Safe boot did not worked but last known good configuration option worked now what should I do.

Comment: @SakithKarunasena You are good to go. Answer updated.

Comment: Its ok when i restart again all worked fine and thanks fir the help in advance

Comment: If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the accept button (the tick ✓ button).

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with my BH12LS38 LG BluRay drive. It just can't read discs at all. "Last Good Configuration" is the way to go.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).